# How can I run some specific iOS Swift code only if it's run in Debug mode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have some code that sets some "developer only" settings when loading my app. I want to be able to have these settings turn on automatically **only** when my app is run for development (whether that's via Xcode, Simulator, in debug-mode, on a development device, etc).

What is the proper way to set this up so my "developer only" settings don't get accidentally released and used in the real world within my app.

```
// FIX ME: **** ADMIN CODE ****
// Turn off before uploading to production!

self.unlockCount = 10
self.unlockByItemCount = false
self.withIntro = false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to do this is with a macro.

```
#if DEBUG
    self.unlockCount = 10
    self.unlockByItemCount = false
    self.withIntro = false
#endif
```

Comment: The second paragraph and code is wrong. The Active Compilation Conditions _already_ include `DEBUG`.

Comment: AFAIK Those preproceessor macros aren't available in Swift

Comment: @Alexander They are available, but it is called 'Additional Swift Flags`. In Xcode project, add '-D DEBUG' in 'Build Settings -> Additional Swift Flags'